# How to get Video width and height from a network url

Tags: android, android-videoview

How to get Video width and height from network URL?

I want to set video height width based on the orientation and WH to shows surfaceView in Feed listing.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                int width = mp.getVideoWidth();
                int height = mp.getVideoHeight();
            }
        });
```